# Flutter Animation - Exploding an Image so the Image Colour Fills the Screen

Tags: flutter

I want to perform the following animation on an image in flutter for the splash screen for an app, a bit like the twitter app:

1. the image to reduce in size
2. the image to fill the screen **so that the entire screen is the colour of the image** (giving the effect that the user is moving into it).
3. once the animation completes I want to continue to the home screen

This is what i have so far, which simply shows the image increase in size to the height of 100, but if I increase the size beyond the size of the device then flutter complains.

Any help appreciated.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/animation.dart';

class AnimatedLogo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AnimatedLogoState createState() => _AnimatedLogoState();
}

class _AnimatedLogoState extends State<AnimatedLogo> with TickerProviderStateMixin {

    AnimationController _controller;
    Animation<double> _animation;

    initState() {
      super.initState();
      _controller = AnimationController(
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 2000), vsync: this, value: 0.1);
      _animation = CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: Curves.bounceIn);

      _controller.forward();
    }

    @override
    dispose() {
      _controller.dispose();
      super.dispose();
    }

    Widget build(BuildContext context) {

      return Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: ScaleTransition(
              scale: _animation,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children:[
                    //Icon(Icons.check, size: 100.0,color: Colors.green),
                    Image.asset("lib/assets/logo/image.png", height:100),
                  ]
              )
          )
      );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need some way to contain the image so it is cropped while expanding outside the screen bounds. Try [Expanded](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) as a container sized to the screen and [FittedBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FittedBox-class.html) with BoxFit.fill to take care of cropping.

Alternatively this sounds like a job for [Flare Animation](https://pub.dev/packages/flare_flutter).